# MongoDB - Does cursor get documents from disk in batches?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, cursor

I am performing a large aggregation operation on my mongo database once every 24 hours (60m records => 6m records). In order to prevent my server from exploding I am trying to paginate the aggregation (~10,000 records at a time), then I loop.

I can either loop using the cursor .next(), or using .toArray() and then looping over the array. From the mongo documentation (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor) it appears that:

- cursor will get a batch of documents from the server and store them to **disk**
- whereas .toArray() will iterate over the cursor's documents and push them into **memory**.

My question is this, when I use cursor.next() does it get documents from disk in batches, or one at a time?

Would .toArray() be more performant in the case where I want to loop over 10k records at a time and push them to another collection? The documentation states that .toArray() "consumes the cursor", under the hood is it pulling one document at a time from disk?

Thanks

Comment: Implementation of `toArray` from the mongo shell `function () {   if (this._arr) return this._arr; var a = []; while (this.hasNext()) a.push(this.next()); this._arr = a; return a; }`. That's pretty much the same thing in ALL driver implementations. Just a wrapper calling `cursor.next()` whilst the cursor still has results and turning it into an array. No special magic. It's all a "cursor", because that's the **ONLY** way data is returned from the database. Everything else is "just a wrapper". No difference.

Comment: I see, so no performance benefit from .toArray(). thx!